# How to show the interpretability of NMF by a small qualitative example on a toy data?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, machine-learning, matrix-decomposition

In some paper, such as, [Nonnegative Matrix Factorization: A Comprehensive Review](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6165290), I see the interpretability of Nonnegative matrix factorization (NMF). However, I don't know the means of this. How to show the interpretability of NMF by a small qualitative example on a toy data?

In addition, what is interpretability? Especially in Non-negative Matrix Factorization, how to understand interpretability?

Comment: There are some kind of matrices for which the exact NMF solution is unique, is that what you want ?

Comment: This is not my want. Here, the Abstract of  NMF: A Comprehensive Review —Nonnegative Matrix Factorization (NMF), a relatively novel paradigm for dimensionality reduction, has been in the ascendant since its inception. It incorporates the nonnegativity constraint and thus obtains the parts-based representation as well as enhancing the interpretability of the issue correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an example of prediction of user movie ranking, having initially one sparse matrix "users-movies". Basic assumption is that each user is associated with a vector of preferable genre and each movie is associated with the vector of the same length, that shows its genre mixture.

In such a case nonnegative matrix decomposition has clear meaning, like the one written above, that is it's interpretable in some way.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it further? I feel you're right, but I'm not familiar with the field of recommendation systems.

Comment: Let $X \in \mathbf{R}^{N \times M}$ be a matrix of user scores of movies, each row corresponds to some user, and each column to some movie. Such matrix is probably sparse, since not all users watched all the movies. We want to predict user's score for a movie that she haven't seen. One model is to think, that this score is equal to $\langle u, v \rangle$, where $u$ is some vector that show this user preferences, and $v$ is a vector that shows specific movie's genre mixture. That is, $X = U V^T$. We assume here that scores, genre mixtures and user preferences are nonnegative.